# Vercel SWR optimistic updates and full type-checking

Tags: typescript, swr

I am using an SWR mutation to update a simple record, I am unsure as to how to get full type-checking for optimistic data and cache responses, rather than using "any" type.

The `client` is a Yoga GraphQL client.

```js
type MyDetails = {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
}

type UpdateMyDetailsResponse = {
    updateMyDetails: MyDetails
}

const mutateMyDetails = (details: MyDetails) =>
    mutate( // This generic type is inferred from client.request return value
        'my-details',
        () =>
            client.request<UpdateMyDetailsResponse>(
                gql`
                    mutation UpdateMyDetails($details: MyDetails!) {
                        updateMyDetails(details: $details) {
                            firstName
                            lastName
                        }
                    }
                `,
                { details },
            ),
        {
            optimisticData: { updateMyDetails: { ...details } }, // any
            rollbackOnError: true,
            populateCache: (result, currentData) => result, // any
            revalidate: false
        },
    )
```

VS Code "knows" that the type of the mutation is `UpdateMyDetailsResponse`, but the types for `optimisticData` and `populateCache` are `any`, not the specific return type of the mutation, so I lose useful type-checks here.

It seems the type of the SWR mutation function is what specifies the any:

```js
declare const mutate: ScopedMutator<any>;
```

`ScopedMutator` itself is declared like this:

```js
interface ScopedMutator<Data = any> {
    <T = Data>(matcher: (key?: Arguments) => boolean, data?: T | Promise<T> | MutatorCallback<T>, opts?: boolean | MutatorOptions<Data>): Promise<Array<T | undefined>>;
    <T = Data>(key: Arguments, data?: T | Promise<T> | MutatorCallback<T>, opts?: boolean | MutatorOptions<Data>): Promise<T | undefined>;
}
```

How can I get full type-checking for mutations like this?